# find binary permutations in python

Tags: python-3.x, binary

I'm looking for a way to find all binary permutations with x amount of '1'.
For example:

(length = 2)
x = 1 (so: find all permutations of 1 and 0 with the length 2 which have one 1 in them)

`l = ['01', '10']`

x = 2 (so: find all permutations of 1 and 0 with the length 2 which have two 1 in them)

`l = ['11']`

so far i have this which calculates all possible permutations but i'm not sure how to 'filter' them by the '1's (especially when the size is 7 for example)

```
pre = list(map(''.join, itertools.product('01',repeat=2)))
```

i'm looking for something faster/better than my for loop which counts '1'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
l=7
x=6
set(itertools.permutations([1]*x + [0]*(l-x)))
```

results in:

```
{(0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1),
 (1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1),
 (1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1),
 (1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1),
 (1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1),
 (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1),
 (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0)}
```